# How to send a Portainer Webhook to recreate a container

Tags: portainer

I use Portainer v2.13.1. With a private secured Docker Registry.
After activating the Container webhook in Portainer, I do a POST Request to generated URL.

[image]

But this fails with

```
{
    "message": "Error updating service",
    "details": "Error response from daemon: Head \"https://registry.mydomain/v2/my-gateway/manifests/1.0.3-RELEASE\": no basic auth credentials"
}
```

I  added a Basic Auth in Postman to the request with my docker registry credentials. But this also not worked.

How I must build the request to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as well. It's actually an issue in Portainer itself, which should be solved in the 2.14 release: https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/7004

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 0):

2.14 fixes it.

It's actually because of the way the header was being used in the docker proxy.

In 2.13 you're meant to pass a portainer registryId in the x-registry-auth, and not the docker credentials.  I bet few have seen this little gem in the documentation.

https://github.com/portainer/portainer/blob/develop/api/api-description.md#private-registry

It's because we were kind of overriding the standard header.  But we've sorted that now so it'll take either option.

Fix applied here:
https://github.com/portainer/portainer/pull/7037